# $stateprovider throws 404 if i visit link directly from url bar

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using ui.router with angularJs and i came across with strange behavior.
If i click trough page everything works as expected, links are changing, templates are loading, but if i visit some specific page directly (other then www.myapp.com) i always get 404 page not found

This is my app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboard");
    $stateProvider
        .state('dashboard', {
            url: "/dashboard",
            templateUrl: "app/templates/dashboard/dashboard.html",
            controller: 'dashboardCtrl'
        })
        .state('locations', {
            url: "/locations",
            templateUrl: "app/templates/locations/locations.html",
            controller: 'locationsCtrl'
        })
        .state('locations.add_location', {
            url: "/locations/add_location",
            templateUrl: "app/templates/locations/add_location.html",
            controller: 'addLocationCtrl'
        });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

**Explained in pictures**

I visit www.myapp.com, page renders
[image]
I click on locations, everything is normally working
[image]
I can also click on dashboard link again and it will work

But if i press f5 or copy paste link in URL bar of browser, i will get 404
[image]

Why is this happening. What im i missing. If you need any additional informations, please let me know and i will provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because Apache tries to serve the file `location` in your www root directory. It's not possible because you have got SPA app without subpages. You have to force Apache web server to rewrite all locations and serve `index.html` page (main page). I found helpful gist for that:
https://gist.github.com/santthosh/7dabf08fa3859361ef1e

Comment: Should this file be placed in root of my application?

Comment: Simplest would be htaccess if don't have full access to php

Comment: i can do both, change php or write htaccess file. What do you suggest?

Comment: You may add it to htaccess file, but please read the apache manual to know what you are doing.